# GWT RPC method call fails without error message

Tags: gwt, rpc

In GWT application I have RPC interface. Some methods works fine (i.e. `RemoeServiceServlet` configured fine), but when I try to invoke another method, it always fails with `onFailure()` method. Ajax call also don't occur (I can see it using FireBug, also on server side method invocation don't occur), but another methods of this service performs Ajax calls as well.

When I try to log error using `e.getMessage()` I get *"undefined"* message. Also I tried to wrap RPC calling code using `try-catch` - no error message.

Can this issue be related with GWT-RPC Serialization?

**EDIT:**  Opera Dragonfly showed error on following method inside generated JavaScript (compiled with PRETTY mode):

`function $check(this$static, typeSignature){
  if (isNull($get_3(this$static.methodMapNative, typeSignature))) {
Unhandled Object: undefined
    throw new SerializationException_1(typeSignature);
  }
}`

with error message

> Unhandled Object: undefined

Comment: which gwt version u are using ?

Comment: @RAS when compiling I get a waring for field with type `Serializable`. But I used as well `Serializable` fields in another project, so problem not related with it.

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida I use GWT 2.4

Comment: This type of problem doesn't occur at compile time. At run time, check your console as well as development mode just before you're reaching upto `onFailure()`. There must be some warning that can lead us.

Comment: @RAS thanks, now I get error message. Please, review edited answer.

Comment: I think I need to look at the full code. Can you post it?

Comment: I have looked at the code & it's really large. Also I couldn't find any RPC call in that. In such a case, do one thing: minimize your code first. Remove unnecessary variables & classes. Try to make a simple RPC. If it's executed successfully, one by one add your logic back into the code.

Comment: @RAS ok, but I pasted only Class(with related classes) which I want to receive in RPC call. This class have serializing issues. Can you again look at enum type? I think it related with enum `ObjectType`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19760/discussion-between-ras-and-mytitle)

Comment: if u have any client side model class it must implement IsSerializable interface.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you have a Serialization issue, remember that Java Serialization is not the same as GWT Serialization.

There is often no meaningful error message on Serialization errors when using RPC.

- must have 0-ary constructor
- final fields are inherently transient (ie. do NOT use final fields in classes intended to be serialized)
- collections (ex List and Set) must be annotated with @gwt.typeArgs. @gwt.typeArgs is a JavaDoc annotation, thus it must be wrapped in a JavaDoc comment
  ex.: /** @gwt.typeArgs  */

For more details see:
[GWT Serialization](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.RemoteProcedureCalls.SerializableTypes.html)

Another thing to try:
When running GWT from the eclipse-plugin, a folder in the eclipse project is created (I belive its called gwt-unitCache). Sometimes my own GWT projects get ill and output strange exceptions, I can solve this by deleting the folder and run the project again.